# Is $\mathbb{R}$ complete under the $\frac{t}{2^k(1+t)}$ metric?

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

I want to show $\mathbb{R}$ is complete under the metric $\rho_k(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{2^k(1+|x-y|)} $ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed (presumably this is true). My idea is to start with a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \rho)$ and show that some homeomorphism $\phi$ transforms $\{x_n\}$ into a sequence $\{y_n\}$ that's Cauchy in $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$, which is complete so $y_n \to y \in \mathbb{R} $ under $|\cdot|$. Then I use my homeomorphism to import $y$ back into $(\mathbb{R}, \rho)$, where I use the fact that $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous to conclude $x_n \to \phi(y) $ in $(\mathbb{R}, \rho)$.

I'm stuck at the first step: constructing this homeomorphism. I know that $\phi$ must be related to the metric $\rho$ but I am not seeing the connection. Also, it would be nice if someone can tell me if this is even true so I don't waste my time proving some false statement (although I am 99% sure this is true).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think $(\mathbb{R}, \rho)$ is a homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$. If this were true then the two metrics are equivalent, i.e. there exists $C_1, C_2>0$ such that
\begin{align}
C_1 |x-y| \leq \rho(x, y) \leq C_2|x-y|.
\end{align}
It's clear $\rho(x,y) \leq |x-y|$. However, there doesn't exists $C_1$ such that $C_1|x-y| \leq \rho(x, y)$ because $0 \leq \rho(x,y)\leq 1$ and $|x-y|$ could be arbitrarily big.

Comment: Good point, so this idea won't work.

Comment: @KevinSheng For your problem, it suffices to use the fact $\rho(x, y) \leq |x-y|$.

Comment: How so? How does this inequality show $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$?

Comment: Ops. The inequality doesn't help you show Cauchy. But by contradiction you could show Cauchy.

Comment: So suppose there are infinitely many $n,m$ such that $|x_n-x_m| \ge \epsilon $ for any $\epsilon >0$? How can we get a contradiction? As you pointed out, $\rho(x_n,x_m) \le |x_n-x_m| $ always.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $\rho(x_n, x_m) \leq \epsilon$, then $|x_n-x_m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $2^k$ factor cannot matter as that just changes the measuring scale.  You just need to apply it to $\delta$ in any $\delta - \epsilon$ proof, so let us consider $\rho(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{(1+|x-y|)}$  Now for $|x-y|\lt 1$ we have $\frac 12|x-y| \lt \rho(x,y) \lt |x-y|$  For completeness we only need this for small distances.

Comment: Are you saying it's enough to consider $x,y $ such that $|x-y|<1$ since contraction is a homeomorphism?

Comment: No, because for completeness we only care what happens for points that are close together.  In your Cauchy sequence you can ignore all the early terms that are far apart because they do not affect convergence.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean by "we only need this for small distances". Why are we only considering $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|<1$? And what do you mean by "need this", what is "this"?

Comment: We only need the equivalence of the metrics to hold for small distances because any Cauchy sequence must approach zero difference between the elements. It is OK if one metric is much larger than the other when the points are far apart.